# Within Express, how can I add core modules to my package.json dependencies so I can require them in my js files?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, git-bash

I'm trying to use the core module 'connect' and, if I understand the situation correctly, express uses that module internally. I want to require it manually, and I've tried to insert it into my dependencies within my package.json file. Maybe I'm not installing it correctly with my git bash? I'm taking shots in the dark here, but here are my dependencies within the file.

```
"dependencies": {
"connect": "2.4.2",
"accepts": "~1.3.3",
"array-flatten": "1.1.1",
"content-disposition": "0.5.2",
"content-type": "~1.0.2",
"cookie": "0.3.1",
"cookie-signature": "1.0.6",
"debug": "2.6.7",
"depd": "~1.1.0",
"encodeurl": "~1.0.1",
"escape-html": "~1.0.3",
"etag": "~1.8.0",
"finalhandler": "~1.0.3",
"fresh": "0.5.0",
"merge-descriptors": "1.0.1",
"methods": "~1.1.2",
"on-finished": "~2.3.0",
"parseurl": "~1.3.1",
"path-to-regexp": "0.1.7",
"proxy-addr": "~1.1.4",
"qs": "6.4.0",
"range-parser": "~1.2.0",
"send": "0.15.3",
"serve-static": "1.12.3",
"setprototypeof": "1.0.3",
"statuses": "~1.3.1",
"type-is": "~1.6.15",
"utils-merge": "1.0.0",
"vary": "~1.1.1"
}
```

Comment: npm install connect -though I'd be surprised if you need it as express probably offers the desired functionality through the express API.

Comment: What is the actual error /issue? Is there a problem attempting to install the module, or a problem attempting to use it in code?

Comment: The issue was installing the module. I'm able to use it in my code after installation, I just had to install it with git rather than doing it through my dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save your dependencies in your package.json file do

```
npm install connect --save
```

Comment: Do I run git in the same directory as my package.json file? Sorry, I'm a noob!